# How to send xml file for asp.net webservice using php soap

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I have to send a XML file to asp.net based webservice. I am using php soap client.

Here is the code:

```
$request = file_get_contents('myfile.xml');

$result = $soap->__doRequest($request, 'LOCATION_URL', 'ACTION_URL', SOAP_1_2);
```

AND the xml file looks like:

```
<ns1:header xmlns:ns1="http://something.com">

    <ns1:timestamp>2014-01-01T13:20:00.000-05:00</ns1:timestamp>
```

But, every time its return a blank response. I didn't get any clue from any side.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `ns1` prefixes from the xml?  (Leave the `xmlns:ns1` attribute)

Comment: No its not work even if I remove ns1.